# What determines whether a process is isothermal or isobaric?

Tags: thermodynamics

This is motivated by a confusion surrounding the specifics of how isothermal processes actually occur.

In an isobaric process, if the gas is free to expand and heat is added, the pressure will stay the same (because the piston will move to the point where the pressure on either side is equal, so the net force is equal).

In an isothermal process, if the gas is free to expand and heat is added (but temperature is constant?), the gas will stay the same but the pressure will decrease.

Suppose you have a gas in a container with a frictionless piston on one end, so it can expand freely. On the other end is a heat reservoir. Is this isothermal or isobaric? On the one hand, the pressure MUST stay the same, or the piston would have a net force on it and the pressure would equalize again. On the other hand, the TEMPERATURE must stay the same, because the heat reservoir is keeping it heated to $T_h$.

All clarification is appreciated.

EDIT: If this process is neither strictly isobaric nor strictly isothermal, how does one achieve an isothermal or isobaric process? I came across this scenario as a example of both a fundamental isobaric process AND a fundamental isothermal process.

Comment: why does it strictly have to be isothermal or isobaric?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't, necessarily, but it seems like this ideal scenario is given as the "base case" of sorts for both isothermal and isobaric processes. So if this is neither strictly, how does one achieve an isothermal or isobaric process?

Comment: In the isothermal process, you remove weights from the piston.

Comment: remember that true isobaric and isothermal processes don't exist in the real world - but you can get pretty close by allowing the interaction a really long or really short time to occur respectively

Comment: @ChetMiller Why does removing the weight make it isothermal, and why does adding the weight make it isobaric? My understanding was that isobaric processes occur because the piston can move freely with no resistance, so will very quickly move to equalize the pressure on both sides (which started the same), meaning the internal pressure remains constant as well. If there's a weight, wouldn't that mean the pressure can rise non-negligibly inside of the chamber?

Comment: I think it is both isothermal and isobaric; as you change the volume and work is done on or by the piston some of the internal entropy and internal energy of the gas is moved into or from the thermal reservoir at constant temperature. The reason why you cannot plot this on a standard p,T diagram is because you are controlling both parameters simultaneously for a two-variable system, it is just one dot on the plot.

Comment: @hyportnex But under the assumption that this is an ideal gas, we have PV = nRT, which is not dependant on any assumptions of a closed system in terms of work or entropy or energy (as far as I know). If it is both isothermal and isobaric, but the volume changes, and it's an ideal gas - this cannot hold. Either the ideal gas assumption cannot be made here (for whatever reason), or the system is not nearly isobaric AND nearly isothermal. Which of these is actually the case?

Comment: Oh I see; I made a stupid comment, ignore it if you can... Even the ideal gas law seems to be irrelevant to your question for one can say that in general one has $f(p,V,T)=0$ for some $f(.)$ function of the internal variables. Then what seems to be left is that keeping both boundary conditions on, $p_{ext}=const$ and $T_{ext}=const$, you must violate at least one of the conditions of either $T=const$ or $p=const$ where these are the internal variables.

Comment: In the isothermal process, the weights are removed and added gradually, and this causes the pressure to change gradually.

Comment: @Vedvart1, is the gas in question an ideal gas?

Comment: @David White Yes, this is in the context of an introductory thermodynamics class in undergraduate. Calculus is known but for whatever reason we aren't covering any of the derivations of the tens of equations that all come from a few calculus expressions, to my disappointment. Unless I'm missing something, I believe we are expected to use PV = nRT for isothermal processes, so it's assumed ideal.

Answer (score 1):

in an isothermal process- for example, the isothermal compression of a gas by a piston in a cylinder- the process is performed in such a way that at every incremental step of the process, there are no thermal gradients anywhere in the system. This means that at each step, the whole system is at thermal equilibrium, or nearly so. In the compression example, this means that if you compress the gas by pushing the piston through some tiny distance (delta x) where (delta x) is vanishingly small, you do it so slowly that the rise of temperature (delta T) of the gas caused by the compression work (delta W) has plenty of time to diffuse out the walls of the container.

Comment: If the whole system is in thermal equilibrium at each step, why does it do anything at all? For instance, in isothermal expansion, what's causing pressure to convert to volume (to keep ideal gas law satisfied), and why doesn't the atmospheric pressure then restore the PV distribution to something where the pressures are equal?

Comment: in an isothermal expansion, heat is moving from the environment into the expanding gas. This is the basis for mechanical refrigeration and heat pumps.

Comment: Is isothermal expansion spontaneous? If so:: heat flows into the gas from a heat bath. This addition of temperature raises both pressure and volume. Then the added heat dissipates back into the walls of the container. Would this not lower pressure and volume back to where they were? What is the catalyst for gaining volume and lowering pressure here, as opposed to just staying constant? Both occurances would satisfy the ideal gas law.

Comment: I do not think you are answering the question that at first I also misunderstood. To me the question of @Vedvart1 means that given a thermodynamic system characterized by the equation of state $f(p,V,T)=0$ what *reversible* processes are possible if it is externally constrained by $p_{ext}=const$ and $T_{ext}=const$. I believe that the correct answer is that there is no such process.